# Click event on Select in IE which only triggers when actually selecting item

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, dom

I'm looking for the ability to set up an event on a `<select>` in IE such that it will activate when an item is changed or when the same item is selected again, but will not trigger on mousedown. I also don't want to force the user to keep the mouse down the whole time; they should be able to click to open the menu without firing the event until they actually choose something.

A change event is not adequate as it only triggers when there is a change and a normal click event seems too aggressive in IE (apparently without providing any other distinguishing information such as a different `nodeName`).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try binding to all of these:

- change for whenever a user changes the input
- blur for whenever the select loses focus

And, after a 'focus' event, bind to the mouseleave* event, it gets triggered whenever the user leaves the select with his/her mouse. This is to prevent unwanted triggering (e.g. when just hovering over the select without the intention to click/change the select. mouseleave should be triggered after user selects something with his/her mouse, since the dropdown usually retracts after a click. Doesn't work properly for users using the keyboard to navigate form fields.

For accessibility and usability reasons, I would recommend leaving a submit next to the select. Not all users will understand the automatically updating nature of your select, and some could have JS disabled. Also, keyboard users will probably 'tab' to the button, causing the blur event on the select.

*Mouseleave is an Internet Explorer-only event, it doesn't trigger on internal mouseout events. If you're using jQuery, it comes with this event normalized for all browsers and in that case I'd recommend mouseleave. You could build this behavior yourself too. I suspect it does work better than mouseout: as far as I know, mouseout will trigger when leaving selectable items within the select. For more information, and example of the difference between mouseout and mouseleave: http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/, or this blog describes difficulties building your own mouseleave event handler: http://blog.stchur.com/2007/03/15/mouseenter-and-mouseleave-events-for-firefox-and-other-non-ie-browsers/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can attach a click event to your options and set target manually, e.g.:

```
var i,
  childs_collection = document.getElementById('mySelect').getElementsByTagName('option'),
  colLength = childs_collection.length;

  for(i=0; i < colLength; i++) {

    childs_collection[i].onclick = function(e){
      e.target = this;

      //console.log('e.target = ' + e.target); 
      alert('e.target = ' + e.target.id); 
    };
  }
```

if you are using the jQuery it's that simple:

```
$(function(){

  $('select option').click(function(e){ //or $('#mySelect').children('option').cli...

    alert(e.target.id);
    //do your stuff here
  });

});
```

html:

```
<select id="mySelect" name="s1">
  <option id="o1" value="1">1</option>
  <option id="o2" >2</option>
  <option id="o3" >3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This does cancel out keyboard users, so don't forget to add 'keyup' event and test for spacebar keycode!

Comment: those users are served with a change event

Comment: they're not, since brettz9 wants to trigger the event even when the selected item is the same as was already selected. the change event doesn't trigger when the select isn't changed.

Comment: how would you achieve selecting the same item with a keyboard?

Comment: and who would like to do that?? for what reason?

Comment: Users may wish to refresh the page as they are going through the menu.

Comment: but this can be cheked on load event with currently selected value